# Remove duplicate rows in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am using Microsoft Access and in it, I have a table with data that is sometimes repeated. I'm not able to create an SQL query that removes duplicate data, leaving only distinct data in the table. Can someone help me?

My current table:

```
 Date        | Level  |  Name
---------+--------+--------
 12/25/2021  |   2    | Jack
 12/25/2021  |   2    | Jack
 12/10/2021  |   3    | Ana
 12/01/2021  |   1    | Lenon
 12/01/2021  |   1    | Lenon
 12/30/2021  |   3    | Ana
```

Expected result:

```
Date         | Level  |  Name
---------+--------+--------
 12/25/2021  |   2    | Jack
 12/10/2021  |   3    | Ana
 12/01/2021  |   1    | Lenon
 12/30/2021  |   3    | Ana
```

PS: Ana appears twice in the expected result table because the dates of the two rows referring to Ana are different, so they are not duplicated values.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct t.*
from t;
```

I would add that tables should not have duplicate rows.  Something is wrong with the table generation if you are getting duplicates -- either the query being used or the process for inserting rows into the table.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
This query gets only distinct rows with a SELECT, but how do I include this query in a DELETE? I just want to remove duplicate values ​​from my original table, like cleaning my table.

Comment: @Req_7 . . . I would suggest the you save the results of the query, empty the table, and then re-insert the rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group by of the Date, Level and Name columns.

Use this query:

```
SELECT  Date
       ,Level
       ,Name
FROM   <TableName>
GROUP BY Date, Level, Name
```